# If the results of Weibull regression change strongly if the ancillary option is turned off, does it mean that the regression is misspecified?

Tags: nonparametric, weibull-distribution

I am replicating a paper (http://politics.as.nyu.edu/docs/IO/2806/ajps_BdM_Smith2010.pdf) in which the Weibull regression is used to study the survival of leaders. I use the -streg command in STATA. The authors assume that the ancillary parameter of the distribution depends on a variable, W. Therefore, they turn on the ancillary option and run a regression of the form

streg W x y z, dis(wei) anc(W)

If I turn off the ancillary option, the coefficients are completely different. However, surprisingly, if I generate a random noise and plug it into the ancillary option, the coefficients are almost the same! The equation in that case looks like this:

streg W x y z, dis(wei) anc(noise)

My question is: does this mean that the model is misspecified?

Answer (score 0):

No, by specifying the `anc()` option Stata changes what is being displayed. Without the `anc()` option it shows hazard ratios, whith the `anc()` option it shows the raw coefficients. You can get the hazard ratio by typing `estimates table, eform`. Those should be more similar.